# disable popup after copy jQuery snippet

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

I am using Snippet: jQuery Syntax Highlighter found [here](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/).
While all the functions are working fine, I want to disable the pop-up that appears after every click to the copy button. 
The documentation doesn't show any way to do that. Is there any way to prevent the pop-up or should I use some other tool. 
I also tried using zClip. But even after combining them, I am unable to get the desired results.

snippet code:

```
$("pre.htmlCode").snippet("html",{style:"bright",transparent:true,showNum:false,menu:false});
```

zClip code:

```
$('pre.htmlCode').zclip({
               path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
               copy:$('pre.htmlCode').text()

           });
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out the line:

alert("Copied text to clipboard:\n\n " + text);

in jquery.zclip.js

Answer (score 3):

Use afterCopy callback. Your afterCopy function will overwrite the default alert box. If you don't want to use any action leave empty function.

Comment: Absolutely correct answer (documentation page: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/), no reason to downvote, so +1